# Tool to draw workflow/flowchart of scripts execution and run it

Tags: windows, automation, drawing, workflow, flowchart

Am looking for a windows tool that lets me draw a workflow (scenario) of scripts execution and run it after that: 
example of use case : i have 4 scripts : prepare.bat, compile.bat, load.bat and run.exe.
With this tool i'd like to draw the sequence :
**compile->load->run**
if one of the steps failed then do **prepare->compile->load -> run**.
thanx a lot.